# Manually changed quantized weights not reflecting in state_dict()

Tags: python, pytorch, quantization

PyTorch: 1.7.0

I modified the quantized weights a net post-quantization as follows:

```
# instantiate the quantized net (not shown here).

# get one of the conv layers
tmp = model_int8.state_dict()['features.0.weight']
scales = tmp.q_per_channel_scales()
zero_pts = tmp.q_per_channel_zero_points()
axis = tmp.q_per_channel_axis()

# get int repr
tmp_int8 = tmp.int_repr()

# change value (value change is dependent on the int8 value)
tmp_int8[0][0][0][0] = new_value

# how to convert tmp_int8 to torch.qint8 type?
new_tmp = torch._make_per_channel_quantized_tensor(tmp_int8, scales, zero_pts, axis)

# based on the above step:
model_int8.features[0].weight = new_tmp
```

However, `model_int8.features[0].weight` shows **updated** values, but `model_int8.state_dict()['features.0.weight']` shows **old** vales.

I also tried saving the modified model and reloading, but the problem persists.

Question is which weight values are being used for inference? I do not see change in the classification results.